# Could not find method greendao() for arguments on project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, greendao, greendao3

While building the project after adding

```
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'

greendao {
    schemaVersion 2
}
```

and

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.0'
```

in dependencies, project is showing error : "Could not find method greendao() for arguments on project "

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add the line :

```
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'
```

before the line

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

and project should build.

ex.

```
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the correct dependencies in correct gradle files, like in root build.gradle and app build.gradle

Add classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.1' to root gradle 
and compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.0' to app gradle.